# bad interpreter: No such file or directory while accesing yum

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, environment-variables, yum

On my amazon ec2 isntance, when I do `yum` I get this message

```
bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python2.62.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Though there is not python installed. I have removed all version of python.

```
python
bash: /usr/bin/python: No such file or directory
```

strugling for few days, any idea??

Comment: Apparently yum is written in Python so by removing Python you have broken yum.  Reinstall python from a package maybe using rpm?

Comment: Just drop and re-create the instance.

Comment: I'm *shocked* that you were allowed to even remove python in the first place. (I assume you used `rpm -e python` and not yum to remove it.) Don't do that.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: how to do it?